# How to choose the active slide? (by if-condition)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2-3 div tags that each has different contents. and there is a next button to fadeOut the current div and fadeIn the next one.

Here is what I treid to do, but its incomplete and probably wrong.

```
 $(".slide2").hide();
       var active = $(".slide1").hide();

       $('.next').click(function(){
          if(active == true){
              $('.slide2').fadeIn(1000)
          }
          else{
              $('.slide1').fadeIn(1000)
          }
        });
```

So is there any way to fadeout the current slide and fadein the other slide?

Comment: I don't see any CSS (nor CSS3) in your question. Why have you tagged it as such?

Comment: @Bergi Yh there is no CSS in my code but I thought maybe CSS can help to solve this problem. Like the first answer that used `display:none`. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:
HTML:

```
<div id="one" class="accordion">How</div>
<div id="two" style="display:none" class="accordion">It's</div>
<div id="three" style="display:none" class="accordion">Done</div>
<input type="button" id="go" value="next">
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#go').on('click',function(evt){
    var active = $('.accordion:visible');
    var nextElement = active.next();
    active.hide();
    if(nextElement.hasClass("accordion")){
        nextElement.fadeIn(1000);
    }else{
       $('.accordion:first').fadeIn(1000);
    } 
});
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/theinnkeeper/yDnBX/1/